# Blender Human Animation

Tags: animation, import, shortcut, blender

It seems to be a fundamental problem, but I cannot find the answer.

What I want to do ultimately is to make my custom animation of human, from the model: http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/lex-luthor-23592.html
with .blend file

So I opened it within Blender, but I couldn't find any rigged bones.. (Although the tag implies it is completely 'rigged').

Therefore I was not able to set any POSES of this character :(((((

Can anybody help me please with a brief and short step-by-step answer? (It can be just a minor short-cut problem.)

p.s. the version of Blender I currently use is 2.73

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't see armature because, it was hidden. You need press alt+h or press on eye icon to be open in red square.[image: hidden mesh]